# Add custom header to http call

Tags: angularjs, http, header, cors

I have this part of code

```
App.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function () {
return {
    request: function (config) {

        console.log(config)
        config.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
        config.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS';
        config.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true';
        config.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With, origin, content-type, accept, application/xml;charset=utf-8';

        return config;
    }
};
```

});

and this

```
App.config(['$stateProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$ocLazyLoadProvider', function ($stateProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');}]);
```

Now everytime that run i get this error 
**Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

Comment: What is your backend server?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: This case occurs because of cross origin reference restrictions of java script. You have to enable cross origin access in your backend application. Let me know your backend technology, then only I can go through it.

Comment: because backend is not my part, i dont know much about technology. I think that is self-hosted service in a console application. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/self-host

Answer (score 1):

I thinks you need to specified Access-Control-Allow-Origin in your server, not in your application angularjs.